# Using conditional types to narrow returned instance from factory function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The code below is reflective of a problem I'm trying to solve. I've got a interface specifying some object, that has two real concrete implementations. One impl's methods return `A`, whereas other's methods return `B`. So obviously in the interface I can do `someMethod(): A | B`. I think this would be fine if strict typing was enabled, but unfortunately that is not an option, strict type can not be enabled in my case.

So my thinking was I can try to use conditional type to try and help the compiler narrow down that union type. I've provided some code that compiles. I've added comments inline to specify what I'm doing.

```
interface Str { _kind: 'str'; }
interface Num { _kind: 'num'; }

// Our conditional type say either the return value will be a string or a number
// based on which interface we specify, Num or Str
type NumOrStr<T> = T extends Str 
  ? string 
  : number;

// Interface that clients will use,
// magic method either returns a number or a string
// Here we can (or at least I'm trying to) narrow it down
// by using the conditional type and the generic T arg which
// will be either Num or Str
interface Base<T> {
  magic(): NumOrStr<T>;
}

class AString implements Base<Str> {
  magic(): NumOrStr<Str> {
    return '';
  }
}

// We can create instances directly of AString class
const as = new AString();
as.magic(); // and the return value of this is `string`

class ANumber implements Base<Num> {
  magic(): NumOrStr<Num> {
    return 42;
  }
}

const an = new ANumber();
an.magic(); // same thing here, return value is `number`

// Now we can try to hide this behind a factory function which will
// return an appropriate instance based on some parameter the client
// can provide 
function factory<T>(t: 'num' | 'str'): Base<T> {
  if (t === 'num') {
    return new ANumber() as Base<T>; // I have to do this case otherwise
                                     // I get type errors I don't know how to fix
  } else {
    return new AString() as Base<T>;
  }
}

// But it doesn't really work
const x = factory('str');
const r = x.magic(); // this is a 'number'. But it should be a 'string'!!

const y = factory('num');
const s = x.magic(); // this is also a 'number'
```

Any way to make the `factory` method correct specify `magic`'s return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NumOrStr` is designed for objects like `{_kind: "str"}` or `{_kind: "num"}`, so you shuold use that as the type argument to base instead of `"str"` or `"num"`:

```js
function factory<T extends "num" | "str">(t: T): Base<{_kind: T}> {
  if (t === 'num') {
    return new ANumber() as Base<{_kind: T}>;
  } else {
    return new AString() as Base<{_kind: T}>;
  }
}

const x = factory('str');
const r = x.magic(); // this is a string

const y = factory('num');
const s = y.magic(); // this is a number
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpisg3sg+ga1ABMAuZAcgGcNyBuZAXwChRJZEUA5AVwFts8hEKQog+dRkyYB6acgDy3TAgD2w4GGBq4AG2RgAngAcUlOAeQQNAC2j7byKBDBKQyAG67uKAO7AdegBGKHDI1FCgAObIKpihYrzBUDJygXCUEEQxbj7WwAjWyKzQ8EjIPqYmCMAwBgA0yDz8sWgYTIYmjXzyUOhQADwAKgB8yAC8yIOWAB6QwpStmEzIyAD8YRhRyMvIZAlJtFKyyACS4CUc9nBgyAg6wBDgC34ByNwZdSnIvHCR+d-OawqLJWMC2TBOFxQEALeJ8JIxOIbCIgSJfAAS0F8KAQcDcAAoWtdkDoIOkbidyPwMAYtmAVABKZAgOBQKAqHxFG5EDkgL6BCzvOkOVTqTTaPQdELCewoSKPaD-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)

Comment: Its definitely works. Thanks. Doesn't seem to play nicely when I copy in new version of `factory`, but I'll look into that, must be something else. I don't think you modified anything else in that playground link except `factory`.

Comment: Of course it wasn't working, I was doing `x.magic` in the last line.